# Using PHP to insert form values

Tags: php, session-cookies

So I have a website on which users can share content. I would like to add a like button to user posts. What would be the smartest/cleanest way to do it?

Right now, I know I could use a submit button with two hidden form fields with values containing the post id and the user id of the poster. Then I would just use my `$_SESSION['id']` to insert that into a new row in the `LIKES` table. Now, that's not very effective. I mean it work and all, but I want to do it so that It is instantly updated both on the page and in the database. What is the logical process to it? Could someone lead me in the right direction as to what I need to learn? Is it javascript? Ajax?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

By users I assume you mean **registered** users with an **active session**.

To be honest, I know that the best way to do this is **ajax** as @DarkXphenomenon sugested, but I don't know how so I will put my approach in plain php.

```
<?php
    if (is_int($_POST['postnumber'])) {
        mysqli_query($connected,"INSERT INTO likes (userid, postid)
        VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connected,$_SESSION['userid'])."',".$_POST['postnumber'].")");
        echo "Liked";
    } else {
?>
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="postnumber" value="3456">
    <input type="submit" value="Like">
</form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

NOTE: `$connected` should be a *link* as seen in [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) and [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

PS, I don't know what else you want to achieve. This code will show 'like' instead of the submit button when you click on it for a single post (only the first time you submit it). Work with it, you can try to think how to adapt the code for several posts, how to [count the total number of likes for each post](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php), if you want to display when [mouseover](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_mouseover.asp) which users liked it, add the ability to [remove the like](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp), anything you want. That's up to you.